# Groupby one column, if the date column are the same, fill in the missing values in the numerical column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assuming for the dataframe `df` as follows:

```
          date  actual_value  fitted_value  predicted_value    code
0    2023/8/31           NaN           NaN       520.994413  LX0301
1    2023/9/30           NaN           NaN       580.967973  LX0301
2   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       650.392867  LX0301
3    2023/8/31    471.459992    520.027310              NaN  LX0301
4    2023/9/30           NaN           NaN       531.199547  LX0301
5   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       600.053484  LX0301
6    2023/8/31    471.459992    511.902229              NaN  LX0301
7    2023/9/30    480.400211    518.202630              NaN  LX0301
8   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       537.890792  LX0301
9    2023/8/31           NaN           NaN        99.216818  LX0101
10   2023/9/30           NaN           NaN        98.624779  LX0101
11  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.690596  LX0101
12   2023/8/31     99.400000     99.221767              NaN  LX0101
13   2023/9/30           NaN           NaN        98.822977  LX0101
14  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.875062  LX0101
15   2023/8/31     99.400000     99.220693              NaN  LX0101
16   2023/9/30     98.700000     98.802146              NaN  LX0101
17  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.738091  LX0101
```

For each group of `code` (in this example, there are `LX0301` and `LX0101`), if `date`'s values are the same, I need to fill NaNs in `actual_value` with the `actual_value` that exists on that date. Taking `LX0301` as an example, we see that the `actual_value` in rows `0`, `1` and `4`, `2023/8/31` and `2023/9/30` are missing values, but they appear in rows `6` (or `3`) and `7`, so we need to use the existing actual values in rows `6` (or `3`) and `7` to fill in row `0`, `1` and `4`. Note: For each set of data in this example, the actual values on the same date are the same (for example, the actual values in rows `3` and `6`, rows `12` and `15` are the same). How to achieve this? Thanks.

The required result is as follows:

```
          date  actual_value  fitted_value  predicted_value    code
0    2023/8/31    471.459992           NaN       520.994413  LX0301
1    2023/9/30    480.400211           NaN       580.967973  LX0301
2   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       650.392867  LX0301
3    2023/8/31    471.459992    520.027310              NaN  LX0301
4    2023/9/30    480.400211           NaN       531.199547  LX0301
5   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       600.053484  LX0301
6    2023/8/31    471.459992    511.902229              NaN  LX0301
7    2023/9/30    480.400211    518.202630              NaN  LX0301
8   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       537.890792  LX0301
9    2023/8/31     99.400000           NaN        99.216818  LX0101
10   2023/9/30     98.700000           NaN        98.624779  LX0101
11  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.690596  LX0101
12   2023/8/31     99.400000     99.221767              NaN  LX0101
13   2023/9/30     98.700000           NaN        98.822977  LX0101
14  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.875062  LX0101
15   2023/8/31     99.400000     99.220693              NaN  LX0101
16   2023/9/30     98.700000     98.802146              NaN  LX0101
17  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.738091  LX0101
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['actual_value_new'] = df.groupby(['code','date'])['actual_value'].transform('first')
```

Output (used `actual_value_new` just to show old and new columns):

```
          date  actual_value  fitted_value  predicted_value    code  actual_value_new
0    2023/8/31           NaN           NaN       520.994413  LX0301        471.459992
1    2023/9/30           NaN           NaN       580.967973  LX0301        480.400211
2   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       650.392867  LX0301               NaN
3    2023/8/31    471.459992    520.027310              NaN  LX0301        471.459992
4    2023/9/30           NaN           NaN       531.199547  LX0301        480.400211
5   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       600.053484  LX0301               NaN
6    2023/8/31    471.459992    511.902229              NaN  LX0301        471.459992
7    2023/9/30    480.400211    518.202630              NaN  LX0301        480.400211
8   2023/10/31           NaN           NaN       537.890792  LX0301               NaN
9    2023/8/31           NaN           NaN        99.216818  LX0101         99.400000
10   2023/9/30           NaN           NaN        98.624779  LX0101         98.700000
11  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.690596  LX0101               NaN
12   2023/8/31     99.400000     99.221767              NaN  LX0101         99.400000
13   2023/9/30           NaN           NaN        98.822977  LX0101         98.700000
14  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.875062  LX0101               NaN
15   2023/8/31     99.400000     99.220693              NaN  LX0101         99.400000
16   2023/9/30     98.700000     98.802146              NaN  LX0101         98.700000
17  2023/10/31           NaN           NaN        98.738091  LX0101               NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below seems to work. You are welcome to point out the problems or share other solutions:

```
# Convert the 'date' column to datetime type
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# Group by 'code' and 'date', and fill missing values in 'actual_value' column
df['actual_value'] = df.groupby(['code', 'date'])['actual_value'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.dropna().max()))
print(df)
```

Out:

```
         date  actual_value  fitted_value  predicted_value    code
0  2023-08-31    471.459992           NaN       520.994413  LX0301
1  2023-09-30    480.400211           NaN       580.967973  LX0301
2  2023-10-31           NaN           NaN       650.392867  LX0301
3  2023-08-31    471.459992    520.027310              NaN  LX0301
4  2023-09-30    480.400211           NaN       531.199547  LX0301
5  2023-10-31           NaN           NaN       600.053484  LX0301
6  2023-08-31    471.459992    511.902229              NaN  LX0301
7  2023-09-30    480.400211    518.202630              NaN  LX0301
8  2023-10-31           NaN           NaN       537.890792  LX0301
9  2023-08-31     99.400000           NaN        99.216818  LX0101
10 2023-09-30     98.700000           NaN        98.624779  LX0101
11 2023-10-31           NaN           NaN        98.690596  LX0101
12 2023-08-31     99.400000     99.221767              NaN  LX0101
13 2023-09-30     98.700000           NaN        98.822977  LX0101
14 2023-10-31           NaN           NaN        98.875062  LX0101
15 2023-08-31     99.400000     99.220693              NaN  LX0101
16 2023-09-30     98.700000     98.802146              NaN  LX0101
17 2023-10-31           NaN           NaN        98.738091  LX0101
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I was the original +1 on your solutions.  Thanks for contributing and happy coding!